# How can I make this print all the numbers?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get this program to put all numbers between 1 and n in the file it creates, separated by a tab between each number. Right now it's only printing the number it asks to input, but I don't know what to add to make it do the rest. Any ideas how I can edit this and make it work? Thanks!

```
{
        Console.WriteLine("Please input value of n: ");
        char[] array = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
        string output = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("1 through n: ");
        foreach (char ch in array)
        {
            output += ch;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", output);

        File.WriteAllText("1ton.txt", output);  


    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add in more details about what it not working -- are you getting an error?  what result are you getting that you don't want?

Comment: `var range = Enumerable.Range(1, int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())).Select(x => $"{x}");` however this will go boom, if you dont enter a int. Ill let you figure out the rest

Comment: A `char` is not a number. An array of `char` (or `char[]`) is also not a number. You want to convert the string value provided by the user into a numeric datatype (most likely an `int`), then iterate from 0 to that number.

Answer (score 1):

The number input should be saved as an integer so it can be counted up to:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input value of n: ");
int myawesomeinteger = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine());
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
Console.WriteLine("1 through n: ");
for (int i = 1; i < myawesomeinteger + 1; i++)
{
  build.Append(i.ToString() + "\t");
}
Console.WriteLine("{0}", build.ToString());
File.WriteAllText("1ton.txt", uild.ToString());
```

You should also check the user inputs an integer and not some rubbish but this works if you type in any number up to 2,147,483,647.

Comment: This is terribly inefficient, don't use string concatenation, use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: I agree, @JeremyThompson but I was trying to stick to the original code as closely as possible, so as not to confuse a beginner.

Comment: If this works for you, Rowan, please look into using the StringBuilder class to create your string.
As Jeremy has suggested.

Comment: @RowanBurghart: You don't even need a string builder.  Just write the first number to the file and then write `<tab><nextNumber>` over and over - files don't have to be written to all at once.  To _"check the user inputs an integer and not some rubbish"_ look up `int.TryParse`.

Comment: I bowed to peer pressure.
Constantly opening and closing a file would have been very slow, @Flydog .